# How do I prevent json data getting reversed when using for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm having a bit of a problem trying to make next page/previous page with loop.

Clicking the down arrow button shows

```
6
7
8
9
10
```

But when the up arrow button is clicked I want it to go back to

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

But instead it's reversed, using reverse() doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone help me?

Here's my code

```
var newsSubject = new Array();
var newsURL = new Array();

$.ajax({
    async: true,
    url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/2nqki',
    data: '',
    accepts: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var obj = data.Data;
        var output = '<ul>';
        var index = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            newsSubject.push(data.Data[i].Subject);
            newsURL.push(data.Data[i].Url);
        }          
        for(var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            output += '<li class="news-post"> <a href="' + newsURL[index] + '" data-tag="exclusive">' + newsSubject[index] + '</a> </li>';
            index = (index + 1);
        } 
        output += '</ul>'
        $('.news-array').html(output);
        $('.next-news').click(function(e){
            $('.news-post').each(function(){
                if (index < obj.length) {
                    index = index + 1;
                    $(this).find('a').html(newsSubject[index - 1]);
                }  
            });
            return false;
        });
        $('.prev-news').click(function(e){
            $('.news-post').each(function(){
                if(index != 0) {
                    index = index - 1;
                    $(this).find('a').html(newsSubject[index - 5]);
                }
             });
            return false;
        });               
    }
});
```

And here's the jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/ykLsm3da/1/

Comment: The JSON is not being reversed. You're going through it backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you doing the backward step wrong. You are counting down
`index = index - 1;`
so everything will be reverse.

On the other hand, you are not using clean structured code. In your case you do something and then try to debug and change it as long as you need to do your needs. Especially not changing the links too.

Here is an easy example to rewrite your code. Please keep an eye on the seperation of the functionalities into easy functions.

Try not to do some unnecessary DOM-manipulations like creating elements in a function and changing in a loop some links and text in another function. Try to keep DRY (dont repeate yourself).

```
// encapsulate frontend stuff. here create some html as clean it can be.
function createListElements(data, index, end){     
    var output = '';
    while(index < end) {
        output += '<li class="news-post"><a href="' + data.Data[index].Url + '" data-tag="exclusive">' + data.Data[index].Subject + '</a></li>';
        index +=  1;
    } 
    return '<ul>' + output + '</ul>';
}
// do update the view - in this case, change everything under ".news-array"
function updateView(data, elementPerView, index){    
    var begin = Math.max(0, index);
    var end = Math.min(data.Data.length, begin + elementPerView); 
    $('.news-array').html( createListElements(data, begin, end) );
    return begin;
}
// frontend button handler
function buttonHandler(data) {
    var index = 0;
    updateView(data, elementPerView, index);
    $('.next-news').click(function(e){
        // sorry, we need one look ahead
        if (index + elementPerView < data.Data.length)
            index = updateView(data, elementPerView, index + elementPerView);
        return false;
    });
    $('.prev-news').click(function(e){
        index = updateView(data, elementPerView, index - elementPerView);
        return false;
    });               
}

var elementPerView = 4; // be flexible - 4 is a good example for 15 elements

// do some ajax - not mixed up with callback-code
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/2nqki',
    data: '',
    accepts: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: buttonHandler
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've not been writing jquery long.

I'll try to keep that in mind.

Comment: No problem and no excuse needed. We were all beginners once :) . This example should help you to clear up and separate things. The main problem is not using jquery rather than write semantic code (jquery is just a toolset). My code example is just a small step further from yours to clean code.

Answer (score 3):

As @Pointy said, you were iterating backwards.

All you need to do is subtract the index first, then iterate forward:

```
    $('.prev-news').click(function(e){
        if (index < 10)
            return false;
        index -= 10;
        $('.news-post').each(function(){
            if (index < obj.length) {
                index++;
                $(this).find('a').html(newsSubject[index - 1]);
            }
         });
        return false;
    });
```

Here's the updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ykLsm3da/2/

---

Note that you didn't update the `href` attribute. You will also need to do that to update the link:

```
$(this).find('a').attr('href', newsURL[index - 1]);
```

Here's the updated updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ykLsm3da/3/

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is reverse the direction of the jQuery object,

`$($('.news-post').get().reverse()).each(function(){/*your code*/});` in the previous arrow.

Check the snippet below for demo.

```js
var newsSubject = new Array();
var newsURL = new Array();

$.ajax({
  async: true,
  url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/2nqki',
  data: '',
  accepts: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    var obj = data.Data;
    var output = '<ul>';
    var index = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      newsSubject.push(data.Data[i].Subject);
      newsURL.push(data.Data[i].Url);
    }          
    for(var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
      output += '<li class="news-post"> <a href="' + newsURL[index] + '" data-tag="exclusive">' + newsSubject[index] + '</a> </li>';
      index = (index + 1);
    } 
    output += '</ul>'
    $('.news-array').html(output);
    $('.next-news').click(function(e){
      $('.news-post').each(function(){
        if (index < obj.length) {
          index = index + 1;
          $(this).find('a').html(newsSubject[index - 1]);
        }  
      });
      return false;
    });
    $('.prev-news').click(function(e){
      $($('.news-post').get().reverse()).each(function(){
        if(index != 0) {
          index = index - 1;
          $(this).find('a').html(newsSubject[index - 5]);
        }
      });
      return false;
    });               
  }
});
```

```css
.news-list {
  height: auto;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  -o-border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  -o-border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
  border: none; }
.news-list ul {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  margin-bottom: 0; }
.news-list ul li .news-post {
  padding: 20px 22px 0 22px; }
.news-list ul li .news-post:hover {
  background: #4A90E2; }
.news-list ul li .news-post:hover a {
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4A90E2; }
.news-list ul li .triangle-up {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #9B9B9B; }
.news-list ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #979797;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BBBBBB; }
.news-list ul li .triangle-down {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #9B9B9B; }
.news-list ul .next-li {
  padding: 0 22px; }
.news-list ul .next-li a {
  border: none;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px 0; }
.news-list ul .next-li:hover {
  background: #4A90E2; }
.news-list ul .next-li:hover a {
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4A90E2; }
.news-list ul .prev-li {
  padding: 0 22px; }
.news-list ul .prev-li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px 0; }
.news-list ul .prev-li:hover {
  background: #4A90E2; }
.news-list ul .prev-li:hover a {
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4A90E2; }
li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news-list medium-4 small-12 columns">
  <ul class="news-array-block">
    <li class="text-center prev-li"><a href="#" class="prev-news"><span class="triangle-up"></span></a></li>
    <li class="news-array"></li>

    <li class="text-center next-li"><a href="#" class="next-news"><span class="triangle-down"></span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```